# How to search across mangled symbols with Ctags on Vim?

Tags: vim, ctags, name-mangling

I am working on a large mixed C/Asm projects and I have a lot of variables and symbols that are mangled on the ASM side. So on Vim I cannot just do `<C-]>` on `_foo` because Ctags cannot link it to `foo` on the C namespace.

How can I tell either Vim or Ctags to extend the search on mangled symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim performs a whole-word search by default but you can force it to perform a regex search by prepending your tag name with a slash:

```
:tag /foo
```

There's unfortunately no option to change that behavior or "regex" alternative to `<C-]>` but you can create one pretty easily:

```
nnoremap <key> :tjump /<C-r><C-w><CR>
```

NOTE: I've used `:tjump` because I find it more useful than `:tag`. YMMV.